# Remove zeros from begining

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to remove zeros in value using regex(non capturing group). Does anyone have an idea?

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?:[0]+)?(\\S+)").matcher("00100");//.group(0));
//Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);

if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("value   "+matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: found a solution   ...public static final String extractValuesFromRegex(String regex,String input){
  String extractevalue=input;
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
     
        if(matcher.matches() && matcher.groupCount()>0) {
         extractevalue=matcher.group(1);
        }
        return extractevalue;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    extractValuesFromRegex("(?:0+|)(\\d+)", "00123");
    extractValuesFromRegex("(?:0+|)(\\d+)", "123");
    extractValuesFromRegex("(\\d+)", "00123");
    extractValuesFromRegex("(\\d+)", "00123");
}

public static final String extractValuesFromRegex(String regex, String input) {
    String extractevalue = input;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        extractevalue = matcher.group(1);
    }
    return extractevalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove leading zeroes, you can just use `replaceAll`:

```
String input = "00100";
input = input.replaceAll("^0+([^0].*)$", "$1");
```

## Regex101

Comment: Thx but I want to remove whenever I needed.

Comment: `whenever I needed` ... what does this even mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replaceAll("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

Comment: Thx but I need to remove whenever I needed